# A component type called voltage release

Tags: components, component-selection

There is an electrical component called voltage release, and shunt trip release . what are those and what do they do?

Comment: sounds like an alternative terminology for what is generally referred to as a circuit breaker and/or ground fault interrupter.

Comment: Do you have an access to Google?

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Maybe you should explain what Google is before talking about it.

Comment: See addition to Tony's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an industrial breaker for over current or under voltage

http://www2.schneider-electric.com/documents/electrical-distribution/en/shared/interactive-catalogue/lvped2080003en/EN/pdfs/page_039.pdf

**_______________________________________**

I'm adding this to Tony's correct answer as I prepared the following and then found the question had been closed while I was working on it. As the question is fully understandable and Tony's answer is correct adding this is 'the obviously right thing to do'.

Tony may edit, add to or delete this as desired. Others should leave it alone.

RM.

**_________________**

Tony Stewart found a [**data sheet**](http://www2.schneider-electric.com/documents/electrical-distribution/en/shared/interactive-catalogue/lvped2080003en/EN/pdfs/page_039.pdf)  that refers to exactly what you are asking about. They explain the terms.

It refers to the operation of an auxilliary add on to a circuit breaker which allows use of external control signals to provide both remote tripping and anti-reset control of a circuit breaker. From the above data sheet, slightly edited:

**Remote tripping**

Shunt Trip (SHT) or Under Voltage Release (UVR).

**Shunt Trip (SHT)**

This release trips the circuit breaker when the control voltage rises above 0.7 x Un
Control signals can be of the impulse type (u 20 ms) or maintained.

**Under Voltage Release (UVR)**

This release trips the circuit breaker when the control voltage drops below a
tripping threshold of between 0.35 and 0.7 times the rated voltage

Circuit breaker closing is possible only if the voltage exceeds 0.85 times the rated voltage.

**Operation**

When the circuit breaker has been tripped by an SHT or UVR release, it must be reset locally:

SHT or UVR tripping takes priority over manual closing.
In the presence of a standing trip order, closing of the contacts, even temporarily, is not possible.

Circuit breaker tripping by an SHT or UVR release meets the requirements of
standard IEC 60947-2.

Comment: It would be more correct to say that shunt trip and under voltage release are optional features that are available for some circuit breakers.

Comment: true, I was just matching the "one" he read about